# What should we do with invalidated answers to a reopened question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopening

[*Did type-in-programs ...?*](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27370/7946) was closed as being opinion-based, but not until it had garnered a whole lot of anecdotal answers.  Now the question has been greatly improved to ask for actual evidence, it's a candidate for reopening.  What should we do with those answers, written in good faith, that don't address the updated question's requirement for actual research?

Should they be deleted?  Downvoted?  Something else?

Comment: We _could_ slap a post notice on them…

Comment: What's a 'post notice'?  Thanks.

Comment: A lot of answers on Retrocomputing are anecdotal.  We could just leave them be.

Comment: It’s not like the ‘scientific studies’ weren’t put there just to make the question technically objective and skirt the ‘opinion-based’ closure criterion…

Answer (score 3):

Oh well ... "[Ein Fass ohne Boden](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fass_ohne_Boden)" :))

> Did type-in-programs ...? was closed as being opinion-based,

I wasn't happy about that. While I doubt that there is any 'hard' answer ever, it does shed light on an important aspect of computing back then (and less visible today). Wouldn't mind if it get's reopened (but haven't voted for that so far).

> but not until it had garnered a whole lot of anecdotal answers.

Yes, it's one of that topics that touches next to everyone - almost independent of age (ok, lets say anyone over 35 :), computer and upbringing.

> Now the question has been greatly improved to ask for actual evidence, it's a candidate for reopening.

Not sure where to see any difference, except for wording. Already the very first iteration asked:

*"Are there any scientific studies on this and if so, what was the result?"*

> What should we do with those answers, written in good faith, that don't address the updated question's requirement for actual research?

Nothing. I suspect next to all of them would have as well showed up with the original wording - as mentioned, this question touches a nerve. We all have sat over listings in magazines, books (*1) and manuals, typing them in or just reading them. So it's quite understandable that there many feel they need to add their story.

In fact, I don't see it as bad at all, as they document the influence it had. IMHO even way more than any local random sample at one point in time could ever deliver.

> Should they be deleted?

No. They are answers, maybe not great ones but they are.

> Downvoted?

Not unless they miss the topic - which then again isn't different from handling answers to any other question.

---

The only one I'm a bit baffled is [the top rated one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27378/6659), which seems to me as a very pointy comment with next to no information and support. But yeah, it does hit that very nerve :)

---

*1 - The one who hasn't at least peeked into [David Ahl's Basic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC_Computer_Games) throw the first stone.